# how to insert "|" in "-" every 5 like this?

Tags: python, loops, printing

I want to do like this picture, but I have no idea to insert "|"
[image]

and this is my code.

```
"""test"""
def counts():
    """process"""
    text = input()
    text_abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    for i in text_abc:
        count_text = text.count(i)
        if count_text > 0:
            ans = "-"* count_text
            print("%s : %s"%(i, ans))
counts()
```

it output like this

```
my input:"aaaaaaaabbbbbcccdd"
my output:
a : --------
b : -----
c : ---
d : --
```

how can i do? Thanks in advance for any help that you are able to provide.
ps. sorry for my english,I'm not good in english

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would just be to put it into `ans` via `str.replace()`, which will by default replace an arbitrary number of occurrences starting at the front:

```
ans = ("-" * count_text).replace('-----', '-----|')
```

```
>>> counts()
aaaaaaaabbbbbcccdd
a : -----|---
b : -----|
c : ---
d : --
```

Comment: this is best XD

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it like this:

```
ans = "-" * count_text
ans = '|'.join(ans[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(ans), 5))
```

full code:

```
def counts():
    """process"""
    text = input()
    text_abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    for i in text_abc:
        count_text = text.count(i)
        if count_text > 0:
            ans = "-" * count_text
            ans = '|'.join(ans[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(ans), 5))
            print("%s : %s"%(i, ans))

counts()
```

output:

ex.1

```
"aaaaaaaabbbbbcccdd"
a : -----|---
b : -----
c : ---
d : --
```

ex.2

```
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbcccccccccccccccccccccddyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
a : -----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-
b : ----
c : -----|-----|-----|-----|-
d : --
y : -----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|----
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used Counter module from collections package, also formatting is in 3.6, I'm not sure if collections works well for versions less than 3.6 please cross check.

```
from collections import Counter

"""test"""
def counts():
    """process"""
    text = Counter(input()) # counter returns a list with key as the element and value as it's frequency

    for i in text.keys(): # iterating in keys
        count_text = text[i]  # getting the frequency of that alphabet
        pattern = ['|-' if (_ % 5 == 0 and _ != 0) else '-' for _ in range(count_text)] # creating a list in which we put '|-' if the position if mod of 5 else we just put '-'.
        patternString = ''.join(pattern) # then we convert it to string
        print(f'{i}: {patternString} ')

counts()
```